# zeroinfl model fails on input data

Tags: r, machine-learning

I ma struggling to get the `zeroinfl`  model work on my data. Here is an example of my data (Failed) and the bioChemists data (Works) that fails and works, respectively. Do you notice anything in the "Failed" data that is wrong?

```
zeroinfl(y_train ~ . | 1, data = Failed)
```

Error in zeroinfl(y_train ~ . | 1, data = data_train.m) :
invalid dependent variable, minimum count is not zero

```
zeroinfl(art ~ . | 1, data = Works)
```

data:

```
Failed <- dput(data_train.m)
structure(list(y_train = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1), value = c(73, 48, 17, 90, 46, 72, 62, 0, 19, 0, 
17, 0, 0, 45, 72, 67, 37, 70, 2, 32, 30, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 64, 
62, 42, 0, 92, 89, 8, 3, 0, 22, 0, 0, 60, 2, 4, 49, 92, 18, 0, 
82, 70, 51, 0, 12, 0, 62, 36, 67, 0, 49, 60, 0, 10, 90, 3, 23, 
11, 0, 75, 13, 38, 19, 13, 43, 71, 0, 55, 73, 59, 55, 30, 47, 
0, 41, 70, 19, 24, 68, 0, 0, 68, 0, 8, 0, 0, 72, 0, 29, 81, 71, 
43, 0, 37)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")


Works <- structure(list(art = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ment = c(7L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 14L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 
7L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 13L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 25L, 
14L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 6L, 19L, 1L, 35L, 6L, 19L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
19L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 8L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100"), class = "data.frame")
```